# SDL2 MOUSEBUTTONUP triggers more than once

Tags: input, sdl2, events

I've been trying to figure this out all day. I'm trying to make a simple check box. But my MOUSEBUTTONUP event keeps firing until I trigger another event like moving the mouse or clicking again.

```
//If a mouse button was released
if (Sdl_Setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP)
{
    //If the left mouse button was pressed
    if (Sdl_Setup->GetMainEvent()->button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
    {
        //Get the mouse offsets
        SDL_GetMouseState(&mouseX, &mouseY);

        //If the mouse is over the button
        if ((mouseX > Button->GetX()) && (mouseX < Button->GetX() + Button->GetWidth()) && (mouseY > Button->GetY()) && (mouseY < Button->GetY() + Button->GetHeight()))
        {
                //Set the button sprite
                state = selected;
                Button->SetCrop(GetFrameX(), GetFrameY(), state);
                clicked = true;
                std::cout << clicked << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This will just spam 1 in the console (if you keep the mouse still) when all I want is for it to trigger once. From what I've read MOUSEBUTTONUP is only supposed to be sent to the event queue once

I've tried adding a bool to stop it after it's clicked by putting it in an if statement and that works but the thing is I want to be able to toggle the box on and off so when I add an else statement that changes the bool back to false it spams 101010 instead of just one.

```
   //If a mouse button was released
if (Sdl_Setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP)
{
    //If the left mouse button was pressed
    if (Sdl_Setup->GetMainEvent()->button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
    {
        //Get the mouse offsets
        SDL_GetMouseState(&mouseX, &mouseY);

        //If the mouse is over the button
        if ((mouseX > Button->GetX()) && (mouseX < Button->GetX() + Button->GetWidth()) && (mouseY > Button->GetY()) && (mouseY < Button->GetY() + Button->GetHeight()))
        {
            if (clicked == false)
            {
                //Set the button sprite
                state = selected;
                Button->SetCrop(GetFrameX(), GetFrameY(), state);
                clicked = true;
                std::cout << clicked << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                //Set the button sprite
                state = noInteraction;
                Button->SetCrop(GetFrameX(), GetFrameY(), state);
                clicked = false;
                std::cout << clicked << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the system behind `Sdl_Setup->GetMainEvent()` could be the trouble maker here? That seems like the only possibility to me, since your code above looks okay.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 That was the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adapting your program to use a "mousedown" variable. Here's an example you can use as a reference:

```
bool mousedown=0;  // Declared outside the scope of functions that use it.
while(running) { // Main loop.
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        switch(event.type) {
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mousedown=1;
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if(mousedown) {
                    /* The SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP event will be ignored if a
                       previous SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event has not occurred. */
                }
                mousedown=0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't try that but it looks like it might of worked. Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

In `Sdl_Setup` is where I make the window I'm using and stuff like that and the variable `mainEvent` is `= new SDL_Event();` so then when I was calling `GetMainEvent()` it was just sending that to `PollEvent()` over and over again. So all I did is create a quick `void` function in `Sdl_Setup` to set `mainEvent` to a blank `SDL_Event()` and then call that after `clicked = true;` and it works.